# Self-made air pump - What does it take to pump up a balloon?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, air, flow

We are building a simple altitude-controlled balloon (idea borrowed from [Google Loons](http://www.google.com/loon/)). As part of that, we need an air pump to inflate a balloon acting as ballast (which is called a [Ballonet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballonet) in Zeppelins). We are currently trying to figure out the physics of the pump:
[image: a balloon pump]
From what I understand, the energy we put in to make the fan spin will change air flow in two ways:

1. It changes the air velocity $v_F$, and thus flow rate $Q_F$ (between fan and nozzle)
2. It changes the pressure from $p_0$ (atmosphere) to $p_F$ (between fan and nozzle)

However, I don't know how either of them relate to servo power $P$, fan size (radius) $r$ and/or other parameters of our plant. (Furthermore, from what I understand, the nozzle will further reduce pressure, at the same time increase velocity, and thus $Q_B > Q_F$?)

I have three questions:

1. How can I make sure that I have enough pressure that the balloon will inflate at all? (Since we want to keep the pump as small as possible, we want to figure out the min requirements.)
2. How can I compute $Q_F$ and $p_F$ from power $P$ and other aspects of my plant?
3. If I reduce the size of the fan, so it exactly fits the entrance of the Ballonet and replace the Nozzle with a straight piece of pipe of same length, will $Q_B$ and $p_B$ stay the same?

Comment: A problem you will have is that a fan-type (or impeller type) pump will tend to "stall", where the rotor moves but no fluid (especially if compressible) moves forward.  This is fairly unpredictable without actually building the system (or having a PHD in fluids).  A "positive displacement" pump (eg, a piston pump) does not have this problem.

Comment: @HotLicks By stalling you mean, the fan is not able to build up enough pressure to pump up the balloon? That's basically my question (1) isn't it? And you are saying, the calculations to figure it out are very complex? In a side note, the piston will also fail, if it cannot generate enough pressure, no?

Comment: "Stalling" occurs when a "lump" of fluid (such as air) "breaks off" from the flow and simply spins with the rotor.  This can happen at a relatively low pressure, depending on the pump design.  Fan/impeller pumps depend on the momentum of the fluid (imparted by the rotor) to counter the back pressure, and when that momentum is insufficient then stalling occurs. There are also complex factors having to do with turbulence in the flow.

Comment: @HotLicks So usually, air pumps are piston-based?

Comment: Most air pumps that produce relatively high pressure are piston-based.  It's unclear what pressure you need to generate -- you might be able to use some sort of impeller or turbine pump -- but the issues involved are beyond what can likely be described here (even if you find someone with that domain knowledge).

Comment: I already know that lees than 1kPa will do. Anyway. We gave up building our own pump and will go with a store model for now; easy, cheap and efficient. But I'm still curious how power, pressure and flow rate relate to each other, in a general sense.

Comment: 1 kPa is a miniscule pressure -- sea level pressure is 101 kPa.  I suspect that you've got the wrong number.  (If is really is 1 kPa then you could probably do it with one of those battery-powered "personal" fans.)  The max pressure that a human can blow is about 10 kPa.